# Bulk insert records in database from excel

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, file-upload

I am developing a component from which user can upload excel sheet and the data must be saved into database. When excel sheet rows are `250` then insertion works fine but when the rows are `2500` or more it gives a blank page with no error and rows are not inserted completely into the database. I am using `PHPExcel` library for importing excel sheets. Following is the code:

1. **controllers/fileuploads.php**:

   ```
   public function uploadData($fileData, $data,$tablename){

   //Validate file by checking if excel sheet is uploaded
   $isValid = $this->validateFileType($fileData);

   if($isValid){

       $inputFilename = $fileData['excelfile']['tmp_name'];
       try {
           $objPHPExcel    = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFilename); //read the spreadsheet workbook
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFilename,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
       }

       //  Get worksheet dimensions
       $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
       $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
       $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
       for ($row = 4; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
         // Read a row of data into an array
         $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row);

         if(!empty($rowData[0][0])){ //if row is null
              //  Insert row data array into database
              $isInserted = $this->insertData($rowData, $data);
         }

        }// excel for loop ends

      if($isInserted){
       //redirect after importing the data from excel into database
       $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=fileuploads', false), 'File uploaded successfully','message');
      }

   }//if($isValid)
   }
   ```
2. **controllers/fileuploads - insertData method:** this method calls different model methods based on which section's sheet is uploaded. Ex. `Section Test` will call a method `getInsertSectionTest()` from the model. There are 6 different sections.
3. **models/fileupload.php:** Following is the code for inserting data

   ```
   public function getInsertSectionTest($rowData, $data){
     $objData = new stdClass();
     $objData->section_id = $data['section'][0];
     $objData->category = str_replace("'","",$rowData[0][0]);
     $objData->subcategory = str_replace("'","",$rowData[0][6]);
     $objData->year = $data['year'];
     $objData->number_type = $rowData[0][7];
     .
     . // and so on
     .
     $objData->region_northwest = $rowData[0][43];
     $objData->region_southwest = $rowData[0][44];
     $objData->region_unknown = $rowData[0][45];

     $insertResult = JFactory::getDbo()->insertObject('#__testsection_tablename', $objData);

     if( $insertResult){
       return true;
     }
     else{
       $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=fileuploads', false), 'Data could not be imported. Please try again' ,'error');
       return false;
     }
   }
   ```

Kindly, let me know how more than 2000 rows be inserted at once. I also referred this [question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/can-multiple-records-be-inserted-all-at-once-with-the-jdatabase) but not able to form the array of values to be inserted.

Comment: the blank screen is almost certainly a fatal error that is hidden.  can you turn on all errors and stick the following prior to the code you are running?
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @jamesgarrett thanks james but i tried this earlier and it didn't return anything. However, i got the solution. Check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue. Problem was that when insert query was called in a loop 2000 times, deadlock occurred and returned a blank page. The solution to this is to construct one single insert query and then insert the values. Following is the code I added in model file -

Instead of calling insert method in loop I formed the insert values array:

```
$getValues = array();

for ($row = 4; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row);
    if(!empty($rowData[0][0])){ //if row is null
        //  Insert row data array into database
        $getValues[] = $this->getValuesModel($rowData, $data);
    }

}// excel for loop ends

$columns = $this->getColumns($data); //call columns method to fetch different section's columns

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->insert($db->quoteName($tablename));
$query->columns($columns);
$query->values($getValues);
$db->setQuery($query);
$isInserted = $db->query();

if($isInserted){
    //redirect after importing the data from excel into database
    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_componentname&view=fileuploads', false), 'File uploaded successfully','message');
}
```

For complete code and files, you refer [Github](https://github.com/ruchikanagarkar/excelimport-joomla).